# via WPF, I want to add 1 to 10 numbers in ComboBox, Visual Basic .NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

'[image]

Visual Basic

I want to add 1-to-10 numbers in those comboboxes inside each items in listbox.

I cannot initialize the combobox filled with the numbers because the combobox is not a single control but dynamically generated.

Is there any simple method to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The standard "WPF" way to do this is to assign an `ObservableCollection` to the combobox's `ItemSource`.  Requires :

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

then :

```
Dim comboList As ObservableCollection(Of String) = _
                                   New ObservableCollection(Of String)()
comboList.Add("1")
comboList.Add("2")
comboList.Add("3")
' ...etc
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = comboList
```

Alternatively you can also do :

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("1")
ComboBox1.Items.Add("2")
ComboBox1.Items.Add("3")
' ...etc
```

The `ObservableCollection` can be more powerful and flexible - multiple objects can bind to one collection and their values update automatically when the collection changes, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think that my question wasn't clear. I want to add the numbers to the comboboxes whenever the each list item is added. The problem is that combobox is not a single control.

Comment: @klados Then your description is incredibly unclear.  Please try to describe exactly what you are trying to do.  As it is, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do.  How are the combobox items related to the listbox items and how should the combobox items change when the list items change?  You are not explaining what you are doing.